# Using a Keras model inside a TF estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to use one of the pre-built keras' models (vgg, inception, resnet, etc) included in `tf.keras.application` for feature extraction to save me some time training.

What is the correct way to do this inside of an estimator model function?

This is what I currently have.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def model_fn(features, labels, mode):

    # Import the pretrained model
    base_model = tf.keras.applications.InceptionV3(
            weights='imagenet', 
            include_top=False,
            input_shape=(200,200,3)
    )

    # get the output features from InceptionV3
    resnet_features = base_model.predict(features['x'])

    # flatten and feed into dense layers
    pool2_flat = tf.layers.flatten(resnet_features)

    dense1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat, units=5120, activation=tf.nn.relu)

    # ... Add in N number of dense layers depending on my application

    logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=denseN, units=5)

    # Calculate Loss
    onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices=tf.cast(labels, tf.int32), depth=5)

    loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(
    onehot_labels=onehot_labels, logits=logits)

    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-3)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(
        loss=loss,
        global_step=tf.train.get_global_step()
    )

    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # import Xtrain and Ytrain

    classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
        model_fn=model_fn, model_dir="/tmp/conv_model")

    train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
        x={'x': Xtrain},
        y=Ytrain,
        batch_size=100,
        num_epochs=None,
        shuffle=True)

    classifier.train(
        input_fn=train_input_fn,
        steps=100)
```

However, this code throws the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Dimension' and 'float'
```

at line `resnet_features = base_model.predict(features['x'])`

I think this is because the keras model is expecting a numpy array, but the estimator is passing in a tf.Tensor.

So, what is the correct way to use a keras model inside of an estimator. And, if you're not suppose to do this, what is the simplest way to leverage a pre-trained model for transfer learning in TF?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not aware of any available method allowing you to create **custom** `model_fn` from pretrained keras model. An easier way is to use `tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator()`

```
model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(
    input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
    include_top=False,
    pooling='avg',
    weights='imagenet')
logits =  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, 'softmax')(model.layers[-1].output)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(model.inputs, logits)
model.compile('adam', 'categorical_crossentropy', ['accuracy'])

# Convert Keras Model to tf.Estimator
estimator = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model=model)
estimator.train(input_fn=....)
```

However, if you would like to create custom model_fn to add more ops (e.g. Summary ops), you can write as following:

```
import tensorflow as tf

_INIT_WEIGHT = True

def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
  global _INIT_WEIGHT

  # This is important, it allows keras model to update weights
  tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase(mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)

  model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNet(
      input_tensor=features,
      include_top=False,
      pooling='avg',
      weights='imagenet' if _INIT_WEIGHT else None)

  # Only init weights on first run
  if _INIT_WEIGHT:
    _INIT_WEIGHT = False

  feature_map = model(features)
  logits = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=params['num_classes'])(feature_map)

  # loss
  loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(labels=labels, logits=logits)
  ...
```

Comment: This example might be helpful: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/tensorflow_abalone_age_predictor_using_keras/abalone.py

Comment: Using the 2nd the soluiton mentioned above I'm facing the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59046447/invalid-argument-error-while-using-keras-model-api-inside-an-estimator-model-fn?noredirect=1#comment104334088_59046447) issue

Answer (score 0):

You can have only tensors in `model_fn`. Maybe you can try something like this. This can be considered as a hack. The better part is that this code apart from just providing `model_fn`, it also stores weights of the loaded model as a checkpoint in . This helps you to get the weights when you call `estimator.train(...)` or `estimator.evaluate(...)` from the checkpoint.

```
def model_fn(features, labels, mode):  

    # Import the pretrained model
    base_model = tf.keras.applications.InceptionV3(
        weights='imagenet', 
        include_top=False,
        input_shape=(200,200,3)
    )    

    # some check
    if not hasattr(m, 'optimizer'):
        raise ValueError(
            'Given keras model has not been compiled yet. '
            'Please compile first '
            'before creating the estimator.')

    # get estimator object from model
    keras_estimator_obj = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(
        keras_model=base_model,
        model_dir=<model_dir>,
        config=<run_config>,
    ) 

    # pull model_fn that we need (hack)
    return keras_estimator_obj._model_fn
```