# Tensorflow: Integrate Keras Model in Estimator model_fn

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-estimator, transfer-learning

I am working on the problem of **using a pretrained keras.applications model in the model_fn of a estimator.**

In my research group, we are using Tensorflow estimator since they offer many advantages through parallel training and evaluation, warm-starting of training, easy serving etc. Thus **I need a solution that can be used in the model_fn of a estimator.**

Basically, I want to use a pretrained graph within my model_fn and I though I could used models from keras.applications for it. Unfortunately, so far I was unable to plug the keras.applications model into the model_fn in a suitable way.

I want to use a visual extractor without the top layers (resnet50, mobilenet, nasnet...) to extract feature vectors and later I might want to fine-tune this extraction. This would rule out using the visual extractor as preprocessing step outside of the model_fn.

After much trying with my real dataset, I reverted back to good old MNIST and came up with a minimal example to indicate what I am looking for. I looked around here on stackoverflow and followed [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49163547/9840142) initially.

In the example below, I try to classify the MNIST dataset with the mobilenet architecture as visual extractor. There are two example versions of passing the features on and one example of not using the keras model at all. The code is very close to the official TF custom_estimator example. Only the dataset is reduced to easily fit into memory and the images are upscaled and converted to rgb to fit the network structure.

Example cases 1 and 2 lead to a **stagnating training loss and a constant loss in evaluation.** The third case shows that without the model, the loss does get reduced (although overall performance is poor as can be expected) With this example, I am not shooting for high performance! I am just trying to show where I am stuck and hoping that somebody can help.

Ideas and further thoughts:

- The fact that the evaluation loss is constant could mean that the
  model does not pass on the input at all. However how could I verify
  it? In this mixed tf/keras situation, I was unable to get
  tf.historgram to work to plot activations or weights.
- Another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51109026/9840142) indicates that keras keeps one session in the
  background. Though since the estimator API builds two graphs for
  training and evaluation, this could become a messed-up situation in
  the background.
- If there is a way to just use the graph with its weights, I do not
  need the OO-interface of the keras model, but how could that work?
- Setting the learning phase in the keras backend creates bumps in the
  loss also for the case without using the model features, indicating
  the problem of the two sessions, thus it is commented out below.

I also opened an [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25670) on github, since it appears to me that this functionality should work.

Below, you can find the self-contained example. It should run out of the box after just copy/pasting it. Any help is highly appreciated!

```py
        import tensorflow as tf
        import numpy as np

        from keras.datasets import mnist


        # switch to example 1/2/3
        EXAMPLE_CASE = 3

        # flag for initial weights loading of keras model
        _W_INIT = True


        def dense_net(features, labels, mode, params):
            # --- code to load a keras application ---

            # commenting in this line leads to a bump in the loss everytime the
            # evaluation is run, this indicating that keras does not handle well the
            # two sessions of the estimator API
            # tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase(mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
            global _W_INIT

            model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNet(
                input_tensor=features,
                input_shape=(128, 128, 3),
                include_top=False,
                pooling='avg',
                weights='imagenet' if _W_INIT else None)

            # only initialize weights once
            if _W_INIT:
                _W_INIT = False

            # switch cases
            if EXAMPLE_CASE == 1:
                # model.output is the same as model.layers[-1].output
                img = model.layers[-1].output
            elif EXAMPLE_CASE == 2:
                img = model(features)
            elif EXAMPLE_CASE == 3:
                # do not use keras features
                img = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(features)
            else:
                raise NotImplementedError

            # --- regular code from here on ---
            for units in params['dense_layers']:
                img = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=units, activation='relu')(img)

            logits = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10,
                                           activation='relu')(img)

            # compute predictions
            probs = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
            predicted_classes = tf.argmax(probs, 1)

            # compute loss
            loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels, logits)

            acc = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels, predicted_classes)
            metrics = {'accuracy': acc}
            tf.summary.scalar('accuarcy', acc[1])

            if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
                return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
                    mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=metrics)

            # create training operation
            assert mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN

            optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
            train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
            return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)


        def prepare_dataset(in_tuple, n):
            feats = in_tuple[0][:n, :, :]
            labels = in_tuple[1][:n]
            feats = feats.astype(np.float32)
            feats /= 255
            labels = labels.astype(np.int32)
            return (feats, labels)


        def _parse_func(features, labels):
            feats = tf.expand_dims(features, -1)
            feats = tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb(feats)
            feats = tf.image.resize_images(feats, (128, 128))
            return (feats, labels)


        def load_mnist(n_train=10000, n_test=3000):
            train, test = mnist.load_data()
            train = prepare_dataset(train, n_train)
            test = prepare_dataset(test, n_test)
            return train, test


        def train_input_fn(imgs, labels, batch_size):
            dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((imgs, labels))
            dataset = dataset.map(_parse_func)
            dataset = dataset.shuffle(500)
            dataset = dataset.repeat().batch(batch_size)
            return dataset


        def eval_input_fn(imgs, labels, batch_size):
            dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((imgs, labels))
            dataset = dataset.map(_parse_func)
            dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
            return dataset


        def main(m_dir=None):
            # fetch data
            (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = load_mnist()

            train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(
                input_fn=lambda: train_input_fn(
                    x_train, y_train, 30),
                max_steps=150)

            eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(
                input_fn=lambda: eval_input_fn(
                    x_test, y_test, 30),
                steps=100,
                start_delay_secs=0,
                throttle_secs=0)

            run_cfg = tf.estimator.RunConfig(
                model_dir=m_dir,
                tf_random_seed=2,
                save_summary_steps=2,
                save_checkpoints_steps=10,
                keep_checkpoint_max=1)

            # build network
            classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
                model_fn=dense_net,
                params={
                    'dense_layers': [256]},
                config=run_cfg)

            # fit the model
            tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(
                classifier,
                train_spec,
                eval_spec)


        if __name__ == "__main__":
            main()
```