# Invalid Argument error while using keras model API inside an estimator model_fn

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-estimator

The `model_fn` for custom estimator which I have built is as shown below,

```py
def _model_fn(features, labels, mode):
      """
        Mask RCNN Model function
      """
      self.keras_model = self.build_graph(mode, config)

      outputs = self.keras_model(features) # ERROR STATEMENT
      # outputs = self.keras_model(list(features.values())) # Same ERROR with this statement

      # Predictions
      if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        ... # Defining Prediction Spec

      # Training
      if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        # Defining Loss and Training Spec
        ...

      # Evaluation
      ...
```

The `_model_fn()` receives arguments `features` and `labels` from `tf.data` in form:

```py
features = {
'a' : (batch_size, h, w, 3) # dtype: float
'b' : (batch_size, n) # # dtype: float
}
# And
labels = []
```

The `self.keras_model` is built using **`tensorflow.keras.models.Model`** API with Input placeholders (defined using layer `tensorflow.keras.layers.Input()`) of name `'a'` and `'b'` for respective shapes.

After running the estimator using `train_and_evaluate()` the `_model_fn` is running fine. The graph is initialized, but when the training starts I'm facing the following issue:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must
>   feed a value for placeholder tensor 'a' with dtype float and shape
>   [?,128,128,3]      [[{{node a}}]]

I have worked with custom estimators before, this the first time using **`tensorflow.keras.models.Model`** API inside the `_model_fn` to compute the graph.

Comment: Please show code for building model.

Comment: I guess you are putting this `features` dict to input node `a` directly which should expect a tensor rather than a dict.

Comment: I'm using MaskRCNN model from the official repository with 7 inputs and and 7 outputs. Please refer the `build()` method in this official repo [link](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/blob/master/mrcnn/model.py)

Comment: @zongfan is there a way to feed tensors inside the `features` dict to the `tf.keras.models.Model`?

Comment: @SWAPNILMASUREKAR `tf.keras.models.Model()` only accepts keras Tensor. If you want to input a dict rather than a tensor, wrap a custom model class which inherits this official Model class in this way: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#used_in_the_tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs only with this particular model (Mask-RCNN). To overcome this problem slight modifications can be made in method `self.build_graph(mode, config)` as follows:

```py
def build_graph(mode, config):
    # For Input placeholder definition
    a = KL.Input(tensor=features['a'])
    # Earlier
    # a = KL.Input(shape=[batch_size, h, w, 3], name='a')

    b = KL.Input(tensor=features['b'])
    # Earlier
    # b = KL.Input(shape=[batch_size, n], name='b')
    ...
    ...
```

These modifications wraps the feature tensor directly into `tensorflow.keras.layers.Input()`. Which can be later used to define input arguments while defining Model using `tensorflow.keras.models.Model`.